# Zoom app won't cast audio via Miracast

Tags: audio, huawei, miracast, zoom-cloud-meetings

I have a Huawei Mate 20 Lite that uses Miracast for screen mirroring. So far I've been successfully able to share Zoom video calls to my TV, but the audio stubbornly refuses to share to the TV.

I've also shared Facebook Live calls and casting Facebook Live will send both audio and video successfully.

Any idea on Android settings to check for?

Comment: I have the same problems when I cast the screen - some apps cast audio and some don't. It's probably dependant on how apps internally use audio

Comment: Same problem here. Audio from phone is not mirrored. Even with a notebook connect throught hdmi the audio comes from the notebook. Even connecting a bluetooth speaker the sound still comes from the phone.

Answer (score 0):

This article https://support.google.com/chromecast/thread/41716778?hl=en may answer your question indirectly.

I have similar problem on TV Box. Skype works but Zoom has no audio. I have posted question in this forum.

I guess that one solution is to route the "call over internet" to HDMI. I am doing research on how to do it now.

Comment: The article solution, to use a bluetooth speaker,  does not work. Since there's a delay in miracast , the audio and video becomes unsyncronized.